# What is Logger.bundle?

Tags: security

I am running a late 2010 MacBook Air running OSX Mountain Lion with latest update.

Looking around in my system folders I found a file called Logger.bundle and it's in my `/System/Library/SystemConfiguration` directory. The file logger.bundle was apparently created Monday, June 25th 2012 (so very recently). If I "view package contents" inside the `/Contents/MacOS` directory is an executable called Logger.

Is this Logger.bundle some sort of trojan or something like that, or is it a normal part of the file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a normal part of OS X.

The name isn't very searchable, but you could copy the bundle identifier from the Info.plist. [logger.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/configd/configd-289/Plugins/Logger/logger.c) was the first result for [com.apple.SystemConfiguration.Logger site:apple.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aapple.com+com.apple.SystemConfiguration.Logger).